# Laravel / Eloquent : change connection and get all

Tags: laravel, connection, eloquent

I have 2 database connections defined:

- **sqlite**: a connection to a specific sqlite DB,
- **mysql**: a classic mysql DB.

and the following Model class:

```
class BoPerson extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
  protected $table = 'persons';
  protected $connection = 'mysql';
  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

This works:

```
$persons = BoPerson::all();
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$persons = BoPerson::on('sqlite')->all();
```

How to switch from my default 'mysql' connection to the one named 'sqlite'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All()` is a static function.

In this case, use `get()`:

`$persons = BoPerson::on('sqlite')->get();`

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#basic-usage