# How to change Eloquent Builder's connection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have a Eloquent Builder and two database connections(`mysql_server1`, `mysql_server2`) as below:

```
$builder = User::query();

$builder->where('age', '>', 20);

$builder->with('orders');

// Change connection name here

$builder->whereNotNull('email');
```

Now how can I change the connection of `$builder`?

Any helps would be appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278456/laravel-change-connection-in-model-for-one-method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166273/laravel-eloquent-change-connection-and-get-all, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68242784/laravel-8-changing-database-connection-for-model, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264675/laravel-5-how-to-change-a-model-database-connection-within-controller, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066897/how-to-change-database-conection-and-tabel-in-laravel ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel, change connection in model for one method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278456/laravel-change-connection-in-model-for-one-method)

Comment: @Don'tPanic None of them were my answer! I found the answer and added here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to get the Query from Eloquent Builder and set a new connection to that and set the new query to the Eloquent Builder as below:

```php
$builder = User::query();
$conn = DB::connection('mysql_server2');

$builder->where('age', '>', 20);

$builder->with('orders');

// Magic Happens Here
// Change Connection Here
$query = $builder->getQuery();
$query->connection = $conn;
$query->grammar = $conn->query()->getGrammar();
$query->processor = $conn->query()->getProcessor();
$builder = $builder->setQuery($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
$builder = (new User())->on('mysql_server1')->query();
```

Comment: It's Query Builder. I'm asking about Eloquent Builder. Those are different

Comment: oh okay, sorry! 
then does that help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985472/change-database-connection-in-laravel-model

Comment: No didn't help :(

Comment: I found the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using setConnection

```
$builder = (new User)->setConnection('mysql_server2')
```

Comment: It returns Model not Eloquent Builder!